# angular2-google-maps Modal issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angular, google-maps-api-3, typescript

I'm trying to get my Google Maps modal work with the angular2-google-maps projects.

I saw that when you want to put a map in a modal, you have to trigger the resize event in order to make in work. But now my problem is the position, of the map: I can't center it on the initial coords.

Here my files:

**Google Maps Container Component**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'schools-modal',
    templateUrl: 'schools-modal.component.html',
})
export class SchoolsModalComponent implements OnInit{

@ViewChild(GoogleMapComponent)googleMapComponent: GoogleMapComponent;

private certificate: Certificate;
private point: GraphPoint;
private schools_list: School[];

constructor(private rootNode: ElementRef,
            private certificates: CertificatesStore,
            private points: GraphPointsStore,
            private schools: SchoolsStore,
            private events: EventsStore) {
    this.events.openSchoolsModal.subscribe(() => {
        this.show();
    });

    this.points.current.subscribe(point => {
        this.point = point;
    });

    this.certificates.current.subscribe(certificate => {
        this.certificate = certificate;

        if (certificate) {
            this.certificates
                .getSchoolsIdsFor(certificate)
                .subscribe(ids => {
                    this.schools_list = this.schools.getByIdList(ids);
                });
        }
    });
}

ngOnInit() {
    $(this.rootNode.nativeElement).on('shown.bs.modal', () => {
        this.googleMapComponent.resize();
        $(this).off();
    });
}

initMapMakers(): any {
    return this.schools_list.reduce((all, item:School, index) => {
        all.push({
            id: index ,
            latitude: item.latitude,
            longitude: item.longitude
        });
        return all;
    }, []);
}

show(): void {
    $(this.rootNode.nativeElement).modal('show');
}
```

**Google Maps Wrapper Component**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'google-map',
    templateUrl: 'google-map.component.html'
})
export class GoogleMapComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild(SebmGoogleMap) sebmGoogleMap: SebmGoogleMap;

    private readonly DEFAULT_VALUES: any = {
        zoom: 5,
        lat: 46.227638,
        lng: 2.213749,
    };

    private zoom: number;
    private lat: number;
    private lng: number;

    constructor() {
        this.reset();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.sebmGoogleMap.centerChange.subscribe((obj) => {
            console.log(obj.lat);
            console.log(obj.lng);
        })
    }


    reset() {
        this.zoom = this.DEFAULT_VALUES.zoom;
        this.lat = this.DEFAULT_VALUES.lat;
        this.lng = this.DEFAULT_VALUES.lng;
    }

    resize(): void {
        this.sebmGoogleMap.triggerResize();
    }
}
```

I've noticed that when resize is triggered, my initial coords are changed in coords I've never enter...

Any help would be appreciated ! Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use:

```
this.sebmGoogleMap.triggerResize().then(res => { 
   (set coordinates here) 
});
```

the coordinates you set within the "then" call will occur after the map resizes.

I have encountered this same issue and it worked for me.